# NSTableHeaderCell detect mouse down?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nscell, nstableheadercell

I'm attempting to customize a `NSTableHeaderCell` to detect mouse clicks. In the past i've used things such as an `NSTrackingArea` or overriding the `mouseDown` event such as:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Mouse down");
}
```

These methods don't seem to work properly on a `NSTableHeaderCell` as its a cell rather than a view.

Does anyone have any suggestions on detecting mouse events on a cell? Specifically I would like to catch the first click (along with its location).

Answer (score 2):

The way this is designed to be handled by AppKit is via your [NSTableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3amouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn%3a) and

`tableView:mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:`
*'Tells the delegate that the mouse button was clicked in the specified table column’s header.'*

Unless you have very specific needs to actually handle the mouse-down in your cell it might be easier to just implement that method in your delegate.

Comment: With `tableView:mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:` there is no way to cancel the event is there? So if your column is sortable, this is going to cause the table to sort.... In my case, I have an icon in the header cell that I'm trying to raise an event on. I think I almost have it figured out using another method, but just to check, would there be a way to cancel the sorting when using the `tableView:mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:` delegate?